# Не отображаються 2 png изображения на сайте в IE8

Tags: css3, internet-explorer, png, css

Здраствуйте! Помогите решить проблему! На сайте в IE8 не отображаются 2 картинки png.
Html:

```
<header>
   <div class="phone">0 800 303 326</div>
   <div class="login"><a href="">Войти в личный кабинет</a></div>
   <div class="store"> Ваша корзина
        <p><a href="">Пуста</a></p>
   </div>
</header>
.phone{
    color: #465B7A;
    font: bold 20px Verdana, Arial; 
    background: url('../img/icon/icon-phone.png') no-repeat 0 11px, url('../img/icon/icon-circle-arrow.png') no-repeat 205px 11px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 11px 0 0 32px; 
    width: 230px;
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    float: left;
}
```

`background: url('../img/icon/icon-phone.png') no-repeat 0 11px, url('../img/icon/icon-circle-arrow.png') no-repeat 205px 11px;` - отображается во всех браузерах корректно, а вот только IE8 - не видит картинок. Подскажите, как решить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 не поддерживает "Multiple Backgrounds".

Comment: Спасибо! Это правильный ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Для реализации этого можно использовать [pie.htc](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-background). Но всё же стоит смотреть на требования. Возможно, лучше было бы оставить как есть.